# guard_test_runner.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, minitest, guard

I am attempting to have a .Guardfile that all of my Rails projects can run off in my user directory.

The .Guardfile contents is outlined below:

```
# Defines the matching rules for Guard.
guard :test, all_on_start: false do
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)/?(.*)_test\.rb$})
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { 'test' }
  watch('config/routes.rb')    { 'test' }
  watch(%r{^app/models/(.*?)\.rb$}) do |matches|
    "test/models/#{matches[1]}_test.rb"
  end
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*?)_controller\.rb$}) do |matches|
    resource_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/([^/]*?)/.*\.html\.erb$}) do |matches|
    ["test/controllers/#{matches[1]}_controller_test.rb"] +
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/helpers/(.*?)_helper\.rb$}) do |matches|
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch('app/views/layouts/application.html.erb') do
    'test/integration/site_layout_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb') do
    integration_tests << 'test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb') do
    ['test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb',
     'test/integration/users_login_test.rb']
  end
  watch('app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb') do
    'test/integration/users_signup_test.rb'
  end
end

# Returns the integration tests corresponding to the given resource.
def integration_tests(resource = :all)
  if resource == :all
    Dir["test/integration/*"]
  else
    Dir["test/integration/#{resource}_*.rb"]
  end
end

# Returns the controller tests corresponding to the given resource.
def controller_test(resource)
  "test/controllers/#{resource}_controller_test.rb"
end

# Returns all tests for the given resource.
def resource_tests(resource)
  integration_tests(resource) << controller_test(resource)
end
```

However when I run guard in the root of my rails directory I get the following issue..

```
11:53:04 - INFO - Guard::Test 2.0.6 is running, with Test::Unit 3.1.3!
11:53:04 - INFO - Guard is now watching at       '/../../Documents/Projects/..'
[1] guard(main)>
11:53:06 - INFO - Run all
11:53:06 - INFO - Running all tests
/*/*/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/guard-test-2.0.6/lib/guard/test/guard_test_runner.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such  file -- test/unit/ui/console/testrunner (LoadError)
from /../../.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/guard-test-2.0.6/lib/guard/test/guard_test_runner.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `require'
[1] guard(main)>
```

Has anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue using minitest with Rails 4. I added:

```
gem guard
gem guard-minitest
```

To my `Gemfile` and then generated the guard file with `guard init minitest` and everything started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience as well. The issue began after I initialized the **Guard** gem in my project by running the code below in my terminal

```
bundle exec guard init
```

I tried a lot of solutions to fix the issue. Such as

1. Uninstalling the **Guard** gem
2. Uninstalling the **Guard-minitest** gem
3. Deleting **Guardfile** in the root directory of my project

But none seemed to work, as I was still facing the same issue. All I had to do was to recreate the project, and skipped the installation and initialization of the **Guard** gem and the **Guard-minitest** gem.

I guess there was an incompatibility issue with the gem.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**